# borrar un atributo de un objeto

Tags: javascript, object

Tengo definido un objeto vació (array asociativo)

```
obj = {}
```

si trato de consultar algun parametro este me devolverá **undefined** al estar vació.

```
>> console.log(obj.id)
undefined
```

ahora asigno un valor a id

```
>> obj.id = 123
>> console.log(obj.id)
123
```

supongamos que quiero borrar el atributo id cual de estos 2 es mas conveniente

```
obj.id = undefined
```

ó

```
delete obj.id
```

cuando consulte el atributo independiente de cual haya usado devolvera **undefined** pero si hago `console.log()` de solo el objeto tengo algo diferente:

Para el primer caso:

```
>> console.log(obj)
{id: undefined}
```

En cambio para el segundo caso:

```
>> console.log(obj)
{}
```

Cual es la mejor, existe otra alternativa.

Comment: En el primer ejemplo el objeto aún mantiene la propiedad, con valor indefinido. En el segundo el objeto ya no tiene tal propiedad, ahora ¿Qué es lo que ocupas tú, que aún la tenga o no? Ambos pueden servir funciones diferentes dependiendo de tu lógica de programación.

Comment: En [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) se indica que en el título no debe usarse "en etiqueta", por ello eliminé "en Javascript" del título.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En éste mundo de la programación no es que una cosa sea mejor que otra si no la que más se adecue a tus necesidades

Usar delete es muuuuy lento y puede afectarte en el performance de tu aplicación si borras miles y miles de propiedades, pero ¿realmente vas a borrar tantas propiedades? si borras algunas probablemente se haga mas lenta tu aplicación unos 200 milisegundo cosa que nadie va a notar, sin embargo si vas a guardar tus objetos en una base de datos no ralacional o simplemente tienes que mandar objetos al servidor y los usuarios tienen conexiones lentas es mejor perder unos milisegundos borrando propiedades; he trabajado con redes satelitales y es un dolor de cabeza mandar cosas grandes por request.

Ponerlo a undefined es mas rápido pero tendras un monton de basura arrastrando, que si no te afecta no habra ningun problema.

Te dejo un [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/16) donde puedes ver que en un segundo pusieron en un defined 296,204,746 objetos y sólo 10,851,554 con delete (aprox)

Asi que usa la que más te acomode o con la que puedas tener un código más limpio y legible para que el mantenimiento sea mas efeciente.

Comment: Acabas de generar una duda existencial, liberar memoria o mejorar velocidad de respuesta y mantener algo de basura.

Comment: Afortunadamente son valores demasiado pequeños para aplicaciones regulares, en tiempo te ahorras milisegundos  creo que tardamos mas en pestañear que lo que termina una funcion.
Y de memoria no gastas practicamente nada, un puntero debe de estar usando 32bits de memoria, unos 4bytes, gastamos mas memoria usando strings repetidos que punteros vacios

Comment: Mucho tiempo este tipo de cosas fueron triviales, hasta que te toca luchar contra el caso extremo. Acumulando milisegundo llegas a estar colgado 10 segundos.

Answer (score 4):

para Borrar un Objeto de **`javascript`** debes usar la palabra `delete`

```js
let obj = {
  id : 2 , 
  nombre : "el nombre"
    };
obj.nombre = undefined;
delete obj.id;
console.log(obj.id !== "undefined")// no declarado
console.log(obj.nombre !== "undefined")//  declarado sin valor
//para ver si existe en el objeto
console.log('id' in obj); 
console.log('nombre' in obj); 
console.log(obj);
```

realizar el comando `obj.id = undefined` es para inicializar la variable.Si quieres enviar el `JSON` sin el valor `id` debes usar `delete`, caso contrario si quieres llenar un formulario con valores iniciales, estas obligado a enviar el valor a tu Backend debes declarar la variables como lo muestras
En el ejemplo se visualiza que de las dos formas es indefinido pero cuando consultas si existe el elemento en el objeto existe y te lo imprime

Comment: cual seria la ventaja de inicializar un atributo con `undefined` ademas de ser una buena practica de programacion, en todo caso suelo inicializarlos con `null`

Comment: Ademas esta definición como que te da vuelta la cabeza: **En JavaScript, undefined significa que se ha declarado una variable pero aún no se le ha asignado un valor**

Comment: te respondiste la diferencia (no ventaja), imagina que tienes un api esperando ese dato asi sea null si no lo envias te arrojara error (muy amenudo con java y los checkboxs) , caso contrario si lo declaras con su valor null, si tienes una respuesta de tu api y limpia los campos innecesarios seria mas rapido

Comment: acabo de editar mi codigo snippet para aclarar un poco mas el tema

Answer (score 4):

Para borrar una propiedad de un objeto en JavaScript usa el operador `delete` ya que asignar el valor `undefined` no la borra.

La ventaja es que `delete` borra la propiedad y por ende se libera memoria y al recorrer las propiedades del objeto se hace más rápido.

**Referencia**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete